# Filtering data in R, in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I have a dataframe (d_activity) with 15 variables, each variable spans over multiple rows. What I want to do is filter the data if they have a specific Id. These Id's are stored in the a different dataframe called active_people. So I could do this:

```
activity_in_use <-filter(d_activity, Id == as.character(active_people[1]))
```

However active_people has 21 Id numbers so I would have to add or statments I think:

```
activity_in_use <-filter(d_activity, Id == as.character(active_people[1])|Id == as.character(active_people[2])|Id == as.character(active_people[3])|Id == as.character(active_people[4])|Id == as.character(active_people[5])|Id == as.character(active_people[6])|Id == as.character(active_people[7])|Id == as.character(active_people[8])|Id == as.character(active_people[9])|Id == as.character(active_people[10])|Id == as.character(active_people[11])|Id == as.character(active_people[12])|Id == as.character(active_people[13])|Id == as.character(active_people[14])|Id == as.character(active_people[15])|Id == as.character(active_people[16])|Id == as.character(active_people[17])|Id == as.character(active_people[18])|Id == as.character(active_people[19])|Id == as.character(active_people[20])|Id == as.character(active_people[21]))
```

**My question is**, is it possible to, instead of typing 21 different or statements, put this in a loop? Or is there a different way? Something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(active_people))
{
activity_in_use <-filter(d_activity, Id == as.character(active_people[i]))
}
```

However, this keeps overwriting itself, so I end up only with the data of the last ID from the active_people list.

Thank you very much!
Douwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%in%` instead of `==`, thus we can remove the `|` along with multiple statements

```
dplyr::filter(d_activity, Id %in% active_people)
```